# DocuSignAPI- Wet Signature Integration

Tags: docusignapi

Our partners are having an issue setting up & testing the wet signature process. The developer  states in the list of configuration options when creating a new envelope, including 'enable Wet Sign' is set this to "true" but the wet sign option did not show up when he viewed the envelope.

We would like to resolve this sooner than Friday. We are up against a product launch and this is a key item.

Comment: "We would like to resolve this sooner than Friday. We are up against a product launch and this is a key item." Take a look on Careers 2.0, I'm sure you'll find someone...

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by an account configuration issue, or it could be that the API request is incorrectly formatted or missing relevant info.

First, I'd suggest you verify that the "**Sign on paper**" setting is enabled for the account (in **Preferences** >> **Features**):

[image: DS Features]

If that setting is enabled, then I'd suspect that perhaps that info specified by the API request is incorrect in some way.  If you can update your question to include the raw trace of the JSON/XML request body, then you might be able to get some useful feedback on that aspect.

Comment: Kim, we have the Sign on Paper option checked. One thing I noticed was that we got an option to sign on paper when the template signing action was set to "Sign" but not when set to "Sign in Person". Because we will be running an indirect program with many dispensers I believe the "Sign in Person" is the correct option. Would there be a way to get around this "Sign in Person" if we would have multiple dispensers (users) offering electronic signature via our portal?

Comment: Ah, that's a very important detail you left out of your question. I don't believe wet signing (i.e., sign on paper) is supported with the "Sign in Person" recipient type.  This StackOverflow forum provides a means for getting assistance with technical (API) questions, but is not an appropriate forum to solicit help with the functional design of your overall solution.